How to specify specific key in Generic type?
type Wrapper<P extends string> = {
  [P]: string; // error!
//~~~
}; 

type Wrapped = Wrapper<'key'>;

// valid
const wrapped: Wrapped = {
  key: 'string'
};
// invalid
const wrapped: Wrapped = {
  k: 'string'
};

Here we have wrapper with type param P that I want to use to specify a specific key. But there's an error in Wrapper<P>; it doesn't look like I can just pass the type param in directly as a property. How can I do it?

You just need the syntax for mapped type, which requires a type name for the properties. Conventionally, that name might be K for "key".
type Wrapper<P extends string> = {
  [K in P]: string;
};

See playground
